# Will Nginx health check work when upstream servers are again being proxied?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have the following Nginx setup:

```
# nginx load balancer
upstream web_app {
    server localhost:7021; # nginx1
    server localhost:7031; # nginx2
}

server {
  listen 7777 ssl;
  server_name localhost 0.0.0.0;;

  client_max_body_size 25m;
  gzip on;
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_min_length 10240;
  gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript application/javascript application/xml;
  gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";

 location / {
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header   Host             $http_host;

    proxy_pass https://web_app;
    proxy_read_timeout 600s;
    proxy_send_timeout 600s;
    proxy_connect_timeout 600s;
    send_timeout 600s;
  }

}



# nginx1
server {
  listen 7021 ssl;
  server_name localhost 0.0.0.0;


  client_max_body_size 25m;
  gzip on;
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_min_length 10240;
  gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript application/javascript application/xml;
  gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";

  location / {
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header   Host             $host;

    proxy_pass http://localhost:7001; # process1
    proxy_read_timeout 600s;
    proxy_send_timeout 600s;
    proxy_connect_timeout 600s;
    send_timeout 600s;
  }
}


# nginx2
server {
  listen 7031 ssl;
  server_name localhost 0.0.0.0;


  client_max_body_size 25m;
  gzip on;
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_min_length 10240;
  gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript application/javascript application/xml;
  gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";

  location / {
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header   Host             $http_host;

    proxy_pass http://localhost:7011; # process2
    proxy_read_timeout 600s;
    proxy_send_timeout 600s;
    proxy_connect_timeout 600s;
    send_timeout 600s;
  }
}
```

The load balancer has an upstream group which is again Nginx processes
Each Nginx process proxies to an application process

```
                   Nginx Load Balancer
                           /     \
                          /       \
                       Nginx1   Nginx2
                         |         |
                       Process1   Process2
```

The problem here is that even when one of the processes is not running the load balancer sends requests to that upstream server causing issues.
I assume this is happening as the Nginx health check only performs checks for the immediate upstream server and not any proxies.

i.e.
If process2 is stopped the load balancer only checks the health of the Nginx process at localhost:7031 and not any proxies from localhost:7031

I want health check to be done at the application process level ie @ localhost:7001 and localhost:7011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the issue.
The health check were not happening as I expected as the app process was returning 502 in my case.

I had to set `proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_502`
to handle 502

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_next_upstream

Final Nginx LB conf

```
# nginx load balancer
upstream web_app {
    server localhost:7021; # nginx1
    server localhost:7031; # nginx2
}

server {
  listen 7777 ssl;
  server_name localhost 0.0.0.0;;

  client_max_body_size 25m;
  gzip on;
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_min_length 10240;
  gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript application/javascript application/xml;
  gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";

 location / {
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header   Host             $http_host;

    proxy_pass https://web_app;
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_502;
    proxy_read_timeout 600s;
    proxy_send_timeout 600s;
    proxy_connect_timeout 600s;
    send_timeout 600s;
  }

}
```